# SQL query works in Access Database but not in Delphi 7

Tags: sql, delphi

```
   procedure TformVet.sdaClick(Sender: TObject);
 var anID, anT, anN, anG, anSp, anSi, anDR, anDF, anPD, anTr, anO : String;
      anRID, anRT, anRN, anRG, anRSp, anRSi, anRDR, anRDF, anRPD, anRTr, anRO : String;
begin
  ShowMessage('If you are not searching for a specific group of data, leave the input field empty!');
  anID := InputBox('Animal ID','What is the ID of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anT := InputBox('Animal Type','What is the type of Animal you are searching for?','');
  anN := InputBox('Animal Name','What is the name of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anG := InputBox('Animal Genus','What is the genus of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anSp := InputBox('Animal Species','What is the species of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anSi := InputBox('Animal Sickness','What is the sickness of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anDR := InputBox('Date Received','What is the date received of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anDF := InputBox('Date Fetched','What is the date fetched of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anPD := InputBox('Paid','What is the status of payment of the Animal''s treatment that you are searching for? (Yes/No)','');
  anTr := InputBox('Treatment','What is the cost of the treatment you are searching for?','');
  anO := InputBox('Owner ID','What is the ID of the Owner you are searching for?','');

  if getLen(anID) > 0 then
    anRID := '(AnimalID = ' + anID + ')'
  else
    anRID := '(AnimalID LIKE "*")';

  if getLen(anT) > 0 then
    anRT := '(anType = "' + anT + '")'
  else
    anRT := '(anType LIKE "*")';

  if getLen(anN) > 0 then
    anRN := '(anName = "' + anN + '")'
  else if getLen(anN) = 0 then
    anRN := '(anName LIKE "*")';

  if getLen(anG) > 0 then
    anRG := '(anGenus = "' + anG + '")'
  else
    anRG := '(anGenus LIKE "*")';

  if getLen(anSp) > 0 then
    anRSp := '(anSpecie = "' + anSp + '")'
  else
    anRSp := '(anSpecie LIKE "*")';

  if getLen(anSi) > 0 then
    anRSi := '(anSick = "' + anSi + '")'
  else
    anRSi := '(anSick LIKE "*")';

  if getLen(anDR) > 0 then
    anRDR := '(anDateRec = "' + anDr + '")'
  else
    anRDR := '(anDateRec LIKE "*")';

  if getLen(anDF) > 0 then
    anRDF := '(anDateFet = "' + anDf + '")'
  else
    anRDF := '(anDateFet LIKE "*")';

  i := 1;
  While i = 1 do
  begin
    if UpperCase(anPD) = 'YES' then
      begin
        anRPD := '(anPaid = "-1")';
        i := 0;
      end
    else if UpperCase(anPD) = 'NO' then
      begin
        anRPD := '(anPaid = "0")';
        i := 0;
      end
    else if getLen(anPD) = 0 then
      begin
        anRPD := '(anPaid LIKE "*")';
        i := 0;
      end
    else
      ShowMessage(anPD + ' is not a valid query!');
  end;

  if getLen(anTr) > 0 then
    anRTr := '(anTreat = ' + anTr + ')'
  else
    anRTr := '(anTreat LIKE "*")';

  if getLen(anO) > 0 then
    anRO := '(OwnerID = ' + anO + ')'
  else
    anRO := '(OwnerID LIKE "*")';

  SS := 'SELECT * FROM tblAnimal ';
  SS := SS + 'WHERE ' + anRT + ' AND ' + anRN + ' AND ' + anRT + ' AND ' + anRG + ' AND ' + anRSp + ' AND ' + anRSi + ' AND ' + anRDR + ' AND ' + anRDF + ' AND ' + anRPD + ' AND ' + anRTr + ' AND ' + anRO + ';';

  adoAnimal.Close;
  adoAnimal.SQL.Text := SS;
  adoAnimal.ExecSQL;
  adoAnimal.Open;
end;
```

This is my code for the search button which is suppose to find records with the specified data but it does not work. The query when run in delphi however returns with no results even if you do not enter any data.

This is the SQL query which runs when no data is entered:

`SELECT * FROM tblAnimal WHERE (anType LIKE "*") AND (anName LIKE "*") AND (anType LIKE "*") AND (anGenus LIKE "*") AND (anSpecie LIKE "*") AND (anSick LIKE "*") AND (anDateRec LIKE "*") AND (anDateFet LIKE "*") AND (anPaid LIKE "*") AND (anTreat LIKE "*") AND (OwnerID LIKE "*");`

This is for a high school project and any help would be highly appreciated!
`

Comment: I know this is a high school project but please do read about SQL injection and how to prevent it (tip: use parameters)

Comment: If a column has no criteria then simply do not specify any criteria for that column in the query.  Your "default" query when no criteria are specified should result in a simple `select * from tblAnimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use doble quotes to delimiter your strings, but simple quotes. Single quotes are the standar SQL to quote strings, and your Delphi components probably expect them. Also the standar wildcard to represent any characters is %, not *.

To specify a simple quote within a Delphi string, you have to write two simple quotes :

```
 procedure TformVet.sdaClick(Sender: TObject);
 var anID, anT, anN, anG, anSp, anSi, anDR, anDF, anPD, anTr, anO : String;
      anRID, anRT, anRN, anRG, anRSp, anRSi, anRDR, anRDF, anRPD, anRTr, anRO : String;
begin
  ShowMessage('If you are not searching for a specific group of data, leave the input field empty!');
  anID := InputBox('Animal ID','What is the ID of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anT := InputBox('Animal Type','What is the type of Animal you are searching for?','');
  anN := InputBox('Animal Name','What is the name of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anG := InputBox('Animal Genus','What is the genus of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anSp := InputBox('Animal Species','What is the species of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anSi := InputBox('Animal Sickness','What is the sickness of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anDR := InputBox('Date Received','What is the date received of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anDF := InputBox('Date Fetched','What is the date fetched of the Animal you are searching for?','');
  anPD := InputBox('Paid','What is the status of payment of the Animal''s treatment that you are searching for? (Yes/No)','');
  anTr := InputBox('Treatment','What is the cost of the treatment you are searching for?','');
  anO := InputBox('Owner ID','What is the ID of the Owner you are searching for?','');

  if getLen(anID) > 0 then
    anRID := '(AnimalID = ' + anID + ')'
  else
    anRID := '(AnimalID LIKE ''%'')';

  if getLen(anT) > 0 then
    anRT := '(anType = ''' + anT + ''')'
  else
    anRT := '(anType LIKE ''%'')';

  if getLen(anN) > 0 then
    anRN := '(anName = ''' + anN + ''')'
  else if getLen(anN) = 0 then
    anRN := '(anName LIKE ''%'')';

  if getLen(anG) > 0 then
    anRG := '(anGenus = ''' + anG + ''')'
  else
    anRG := '(anGenus LIKE ''%'')';

  if getLen(anSp) > 0 then
    anRSp := '(anSpecie = ''' + anSp + ''')'
  else
    anRSp := '(anSpecie LIKE ''%'')';

  if getLen(anSi) > 0 then
    anRSi := '(anSick = ''' + anSi + ''')'
  else
    anRSi := '(anSick LIKE ''%'')';

  if getLen(anDR) > 0 then
    anRDR := '(anDateRec = ''' + anDr + ''')'
  else
    anRDR := '(anDateRec LIKE ''%'')';

  if getLen(anDF) > 0 then
    anRDF := '(anDateFet = ''' + anDf + ''')'
  else
    anRDF := '(anDateFet LIKE ''%'')';

  i := 1;
  While i = 1 do
  begin
    if UpperCase(anPD) = 'YES' then
      begin
        anRPD := '(anPaid = ''-1'')';
        i := 0;
      end
    else if UpperCase(anPD) = 'NO' then
      begin
        anRPD := '(anPaid = ''0'')';
        i := 0;
      end
    else if getLen(anPD) = 0 then
      begin
        anRPD := '(anPaid LIKE ''%'')';
        i := 0;
      end
    else
      ShowMessage(anPD + ' is not a valid query!');
  end;

  if getLen(anTr) > 0 then
    anRTr := '(anTreat = ' + anTr + ')'
  else
    anRTr := '(anTreat LIKE ''%'')';

  if getLen(anO) > 0 then
    anRO := '(OwnerID = ' + anO + ')'
  else
    anRO := '(OwnerID LIKE ''%'')';

  SS := 'SELECT * FROM tblAnimal ';
  SS := SS + 'WHERE ' + anRT + ' AND ' + anRN + ' AND ' + anRT + ' AND ' + anRG + ' AND ' + anRSp + ' AND ' + anRSi + ' AND ' + anRDR + ' AND ' + anRDF + ' AND ' + anRPD + ' AND ' + anRTr + ' AND ' + anRO + ';';

  adoAnimal.Close;
  adoAnimal.SQL.Text := SS;
  adoAnimal.ExecSQL;
  adoAnimal.Open;
end;
```

This shouldn't be used on a real environment, because it can be attacked with SQL injection. But as an school work it probably is fine (although your teacher will be happy if you comment it).

Read more about SQL injection, it's very important that you don't use this kind of code on a production environment (instead you should be using parameters) : https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/10/how-security-flaws-work-sql-injection/

Comment: Will try that out now!

Comment: By the way, replace the * by %, again this is the standar SQL. I will fix the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. I copied the SQL code produced and pasted it into Access but it works perfect in Access.

Comment: Access doesn't really follow the SQL standard, the same statement that works in Access may not run in SQL Server. I have updated the answer to also change the wildcard. For SQL Server it should be % instead of *.

Comment: Replacing the * with % fixed it! You are my hero!

Comment: @MarcGuillot: Good answer, +1.  It's perhaps worth noting that the constructed SQL quoted by the OP is missing the wildcards, even if he is using the wrong one.

Comment: @MarineXII happy to help. Good luck with your studies.

Comment: @MartynA, yes I saw that too. I'm happy to not having to deal with Access if it works with that SQL.

Comment: @MarineXII:  When you hit  a SQL problem like that one, try reading the SQL out loud.  It seems to engage a part of the brain that sight reading does not and that is more alert to that kind of error.

Comment: @MartynA Will remember that!